# Where to download grubx64.efi file?

Tags: downloads

I research somewhere but I cannot download grubx64.efi file. It always show:  "550 Failed to change directory."

So, can you give me downloadable link, please ? Thank you very much !

Comment: Please help me ! I can't find where to download

Comment: Did you solved it?

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do or why. Please explain as precisely as possible what you're trying to achieve on a higher level.

Comment: Sometimes Windows messes up my /boot/efi/ubuntu dir, which contains grupx64.efi file. Do not download those files from the net - it may be virus! Instead, boot to livecd, chroot into your ubuntu installation, make sure that /boot and /boot/efi is mounted, delete all files from /boot/efi/ubuntu/ and run: apt-get install --reinstall grub-efi-amd64 - this should re-generate the grubx64.efi file.

Comment: The official images can be found at the ubuntu archive site:
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/uefi/grub2-amd64/current/

Replace bionic with the name of your release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I uploaded mine.

[`grubx64.efi`](https://mega.co.nz/#!9kZlGa6b!6DnKgwrFVdDdB94uEf7tU0py0SlAOKtrcI_coWRFFhk)
[`shimx64.efi`](https://mega.co.nz/#!hwhznSDR!-1iB2J2Wr_KYEx-rkpIeuCpJ7pK1xwNf77vmzKuSQG0)

But a safer option is to restore them from the livecd, chroot into your ubuntu installation, make sure that `/boot` and `/boot/efi` is mounted, delete all files from /boot/efi/ubuntu/ and run: `apt-get install --reinstall grub-efi-amd64` - this should re-generate the grubx64.efi file.

A third option is downloading them from the official Ubuntu repositories:

[`Trusty 14.04`](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/uefi/grub2-amd64/current/)
[`Xenial 16.04`](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/uefi/grub2-amd64/current/)
[`Bionic 18.04`](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/uefi/grub2-amd64/current/)